# "Hearts of game" — what game?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What could be meant by *game* in the following?

> "He could tell of a wicked widow ... who smiled so sweetly upon the smugglers when they sold her silks and laces, cheap as tape and gingham. She called them gallant fellows, **hearts of game**, and bade them bring her more."

From Herman Melville's [*White Jacket* CHAPTER LXXV (1850)](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10712/pg10712.txt)
also previous 
[Source: Herman Melville - *Mardi, and A Voyage Thither* (1849)](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/m/melville/herman/mardi/complete.html)

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where did you see this?

Comment: According to Google Books, this is a quote from: Herman Melville, "White Jacket; or, The World in a Man-of-War." London 1850.

Comment: @rjuffa provides the context, all right, but unfortunately that would seem to put us little closer to the truth. The only use of *game* that seems to fit is the adjectival form: Either "Plucky and unyielding in spirit; resolute" or "ready and willing"; yet the usage in the quote is definitely a noun. I suppose we can chalk that up to the archaic, (to modern ears) euphuistic style of the mid-19th century.

Comment: What @Robusto said. This use of ***game** = plucky* is pretty dated today, but some people still use the somewhat later nuance as in ***I'm game = I'm up for it / willing** [to participate in something]*. I see Google Books has over 100 instances of [***his game heart***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+game+heart%22) with this sense - it's just that we wouldn't normally expect that to be expressed as ***his heart of game***.

Comment: ...perhaps Melville was influenced by the equally dated [***his heart of oak***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+heart+of+oak%22), which has over 1800 written instances in GB.

Comment: @KJO: Your "searchable" link (wherein I also found ***heart of grace***) was exactly what was needed here - it tipped the balance so I thought I had something to say that would justify posting an actual answer, ty! :)

Answer (score 6):

Melville's use of ***game*** = **plucky** is pretty dated today, but some people still use the word with a somewhat different (and *later*) nuance as in ***I'm game*** = **I'm up for it / willing** [to participate in something].

Google Books has over 100 instances of [***his game heart***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+game+heart%22) with the ***stout / resolute / brave*** sense.

Melville was probably influenced by the equally dated [***his heart of oak***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+heart+of+oak%22) (over 1800 written instances in Google Books), which has essentially the same meaning.

There's no obvious reason<sup>1</sup> why the specific combinations ***heart of oak*** and ***game heart*** should have become idiomatically established in preference to ***oak heart*** and ***heart of game***. Melville certainly wasn't breaking any rules of grammar by choosing the latter - it's just that it was "less idiomatic" even back in 1849 when he was writing *Mardi, and A Voyage Thither*.

---

Etymologically speaking, adjectival ***game*** here derives from the noun ***game*** meaning ***fun, sport, amusement***. It's only "indirectly" related to the derivative ***game*** = **animals hunted for sport**, though of course Melville may have intended his readers to make that connection.

---

<sup>1</sup> But I would point out that [elsewhere in the book](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/m/melville/herman/mardi/complete.html), Melville uses ***heart of grace***. I don't know how to articulate exactly what "grammatical rule" prevents us using the form ***grace heart***, but that one is *so* jarring to me I feel sure there must be one.

Comment: @KJO: Indeed. I was actually quite surprised to find **64** instances of the word ***heart*** in the relatively short text you linked to. Even when I restricted it to ***heart of***, I still had 20 separate occurrences to look at!

Answer (score 0):

Since I am looking for a German equivalent, may I suggest (as a compromise between @KJO and @user307254) a 'Jack of Hearts' or 'golden boy' which here seems to come close to the context.

Answer (score -1):

Here there is a metaphorical transfer of 'hearts of any card game' to nominate particular people.
According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary: 
HEARTS (plural) : the suit comprising cards marked with hearts. 
For  example,  the five of hearts.

Comment: This seems a strange and specific response to a question that provides no clues in that direction.